# Lightning button icon without border

Tags: lightning, button, lightning-buttonicon, icon

Is it possible to remove the border on a lightning button icon when it clicked?

[image]

```
<lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:dislike" variant="bare" onclick="{!c.downVote}"  size="medium"" 
<lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:like" variant="bare" onclick="{!c.upVote}"  size="medium" " />
```

Comment: could you please share your sample code of component

Comment: That border is there to indicate active focus. This is an accessibility technology guideline. Are you sure you want to try and defeat this?

Comment: I think the blue color is enough for that no ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As sfdcfox already said That border is there to indicate active focus.....

but if you still want to remove it
assign a class to button icon like this

```
<lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:like" variant="bare"  alternativeText="Settings" size="medium" class="test" />
```

then use that class to target during focus
css

```
.THIS .test:focus{
   box-shadow:none;

}
```

if button icon is first element then

```
.THIS.test:focus{
   box-shadow:none;

}
```